# What is the meaning of arguments in the arguments in this pre-1977 fortran program?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

The following snippet is the first few lines of the driver program for TOMS 494, published around 1975. While the second argument seems to possibly refer to a tape drive, it would be interesting to know what the arguments mean. The line seems to give error in gfortran 4.x

```
  PROGRAM BURGER(PDEOUT, TAPE3=PDEOUT)
  COMMON /MESH/ X(201)
  COMMON /COORD/ ICORD
  COMMON /SIZES/ NPDE,NPTS
  DIMENSION U(201)
```

output of compilation:

```
   PROGRAM BURGER(PDEOUT, TAPE3=PDEOUT)
         1
```

Error: Invalid form of PROGRAM statement at (1)

Comment: Where did you get the code?  The first line of the code published in TOMS 494 is `SUBROUTINE PDEONE(T, U, UDOT, NPDE, NPTS)`.

Comment: @Steve It's actually the first few lines of the driver program in the accompanying paper by Sincovec and Madsen.

Comment: @RussF, I see.  The line does not appear in p261-sincovec.pdf, which is titled _ALGORITHM 494 PDEONE, Solutions of Systems of Partial Differential Equations_ by Sincovec and Madsen, ACM Trans. Math. Soft., Vol. 1, 1975, Pages 261-263.

Comment: @evets No, the accompanying paper is `"Software for Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations". pp 232-260 of the same issue. Page 243 to be exact.

Comment: It is not Fortran 66 eitther. Maybe check manuals for IBM Fortran G, but that is just a guess.

Comment: I'm not quite enough of an old timer to know what this is in detail, but in essence you are right - it is a very old non-standard way of specifying where the I/O should go, and probably can be replaced by an appropriate Open statement.

Comment: Looks like I could not have been more wrong, Fortran G likely did not even have the PROGRAM statement, it just started with anything non-suprogram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be found in this manual [FORTRAN  EXTENDED  VERSION  4
USER'S  GUIDE](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/cdc/Tom_Hunter_Scans/Fortran_Extended_4_Users_Guide_60499700A_Dec77.pdf) from CDC (CONTROL DATA CORPORATION)

It was a way to pass the file names to be connected to when calling/launching the program. See page 7-3 (pdf 91).

> Example 1
>
> ```
> PROGRAM statement:
> PROGRAM  FOIST  (INPUT,  OUTPUT,  TAPE3)
> ```
>
> Name call statement:
>
> ```
> LGO(FIRST, SECOND)
> ```
>
> File names actually used:
>
> ```
> FIRST
> SECOND
> TAPE3
> ```

the `LGO(file1, file2)` statement belongs to the loader as explained on the directly preceding pages and `LGO` is the default program name (sort of how `a.out` is today).

> ```
> name(p1,p2,...  ,pn)
> ```
>
> Logical  file  name  of  the  file  to  be  loaded
>   and  executed,  or  name  of  the  main  program
>   to  be  loaded  and  executed.
>   Alternate file names for execution time file
>   name substitution.
>
> ...
>
> The  file  name  call  is  the  commonest  call  and  is  usually 
>   used for   the   simple   case   in   which   the   object   code   is
>   written   by default  to  the  file  `LGO`.

The `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` files are what we call standard input and output today and were accessed by `READ *,`, `PRINT *,` and similar. `TAPE3` was connected to unit 3 and `TAPE5` to unit five like in the example on page 1-3 (pdf 13).

```
PROGRAM NEWTON (INPUT, OUTPUT, TAPE5=OUTPUT)
...
READ *, XO, EPS, ITMAX
...
WRITE (5,20) ITMAX
```

What did those tapes actually represented physically was controlled outside of Fortran and is explained in the manual as well.

---

So in modern times you either pre-connect the files to those units by some other system-specific means, or you use the `OPEN()` statement to connect an external file to a Fortran unit number. We do not have the rest of your code so I cannot recommend any more detail.

Comment: This is my interpretation from a quick read, I may have missed some point, especially with the numbered units. I will be glad for clarifications.

Comment: Vladimir's research found the correct answer for this.  The portable equivalent (since 25 years) is to remove the TAPE argument and replace with OPEN() in the program.

Comment: Very interesting to see how Fortran evolved. I predict that one day someone will see a python `print` statement without brackets and be equally surprised